# How to go to previous state in vue router replacing current state

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

Vue router has a method:

```
router.replace()
```

But there is no documentation how do I go back using replace just like I can do with window.history.back() ? My objective is to erase the current state from history stack and go back to previous page.

Comment: `router.go(-1)`? I mean, it's actually equivalent to `back()` in History API.

Answer (score 2):

From the official Vue Router [docs](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html)

> **router.replace(location, onComplete?, onAbort?)**
>
> It acts like router.push, the only difference is that it navigates
>   without pushing a new history entry, as its name suggests - it
>   replaces the current entry.
>
> Programmatic router.replace(...)

So, you should be able to do something like

```
router.replace(previousLocation);
```

Where previous location is a string with the name of what your previous location was.

Comment: Jair How do I know my previous location?

Comment: previosLocation is unknown, user can be coming from any previous location.

Comment: @ace https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#in-component-guards